# IE10: "Waiting for {domain's URL}" text occasionally gets stuck on tab's title ONLY AFTER refreshing it

Tags: web, internet-explorer-10

I am a web developer and I first thought it was a problem with some of the sites that I maintain but it isn't. This seems to only happen on a page refresh in IE 10. [HERE](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/787208/ie10-waiting-for-domains-url-text-occasionally-gets-stuck-on-tabs-title-only-after-refreshing-it), clearly Microsoft connect team has agreed upon it as mistake with IE 10.

But my current websites needs to have some work around to fix this issue. Because Users does not know its bug with IE or bug with Webpage. Do anyone have an idea to work around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its found as a minor bug in IE browser.

[Link](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/787208/ie10-waiting-for-domains-url-text-occasionally-gets-stuck-on-tabs-title-only-after-refreshing-it)

The above link confirms bug in IE from the Internet Explorer team.